# DSum and Sum returning wrong values

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I am trying to sum up a column of a table. That column has values of only 1, 0 or -0.25 and about 40 rows.
So the results should be smallish. Instead, I'm getting results like 4080, 40920, 44440, 88880 and other crazy numbers.

This is how I'm calling it:

```
sum = DSum(fld.Name, tableName)
```

I'm looping through each field in the table, so `fld.Name` is the column name, and `tableName` is the table name.

I also tried

```
SELECT sum(colname)....
```

but that also gave me the same large values.

What am I doing wrong here?

edit: So apparently it is returning my field name multiplied by the number of rows. 102 (colname) times 40 rows = 4080. That is really weird!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your field name is being mistaken for a number, Try this instead:

```
sum = DSum("[" & fld.Name & "]", tableName)
```